# Multiple JS api calls

Tags: javascript, api

I need to get all users with a specific and have an API url (ex: `https://example.com/api/userType/1/`) with their specific data that stores an array of all the users with their unique API url such as

```
{
  name: "Type 1",
  ...
  users: [
   "https://example.com/api/user/1/",
   "https://example.com/api/user/18/",
   "https://example.com/api/user/40/",
   ...
 ]
 ...
}
```

I want to show all these users with vanilla JS, specifically the `fetchData` function. I think it would be unwise to make one API call and then loop through all the users within that API call(in the `then` promise function) -- to make another API call to their unique API url. I was thinking of creating a closure function with two functions making the API calls, however I wasn't sure what the best practice to do this. Any suggestions to how to properly execute this?

Answer (score 4):

```
  async function getUsers(){
    const { users } = (await fetch ("https://example.com/api/userType/1/")).json();
    return Promise.all(users.map(user => fetch(user).then(req => req.json()));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue of calling same API multiple time based on API response data. How I done is explained in following, Please check whether suits you

- Method 1

https://deepuvijayan.wordpress.com/2023/06/08/js-making-repeated-api-call-based-on-api-response/

- Method 2

https://deepuvijayan.wordpress.com/2023/06/10/js-making-repeated-api-call-based-on-api-response-method-2/